# convert month name to month number when date is not given

Tags: c#

From my UI Iam getting string like 'March 2017' and I want first date of this month in c#.net.how can I achieve this?In jquery calendar only months are visible.so only Iam getting 'March 2017'

I have tried this-

```
string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";
DateTime parsedDate;

DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text.Trim(), pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper format string. `MMMM` represents long month name (just like "March" or "April"). `yyyy` represents full (4-digit) year. Returned date will be first day of the given month, just like you need:

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text.Trim(), "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
// or CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, depending on requirements.
```

Or with `TryParseExact`:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text.Trim(), "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate)) {
    // do stuff         
}
```

If month names are always in english (like "March") - use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Otherwise - use appropriate culture.